# Zend define admin and default modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, admin

I am writing an app that have and admin module and default module.and i want to put all admin files like controllers and views in admin folder under application path and also default files in default folder.
how can i achive this? this is the directory structure that it want

```
/application
  /models
  /default
  /admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like the following.

1. Change your directory structure slightly (add a `modules` level):

   ```
   /application 
       /models
       /modules
           /default
               /controllers
               /models
               /views
               etc...
           /admin
               /controllers
               /models
               /views
               etc...
   ```
2. Enable modules and tell the framework where to look for them; in `application/config/application.ini`, add:

   ```
   resources.modules[] = ""
   resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
   ```
3. Detach the `appnamespace` from the default module, forcing all module-specific code to be module-namespaced. In `application/config/application.ini`, add:

   ```
   resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
   ```

   So, for example, a model in the default module would appear in file `./application/modules/default/models/MyModel.php` and would be named `Default_Model_MyModel`.
4. Enable appnamespace for your top-level models, controllers, etc. In `application/config/application.ini`:

   ```
   appnamespace = "Application_"
   ```

   So, a top-level model, to be usable by all modules, in the file `./application/models/MyModel.php` would be named `Application_Model_MyModel`.

Not fully tested, but something along those lines ought to work.